# How to run plain Mocha tests within Meteor test framework

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, meteor, mocha.js

I am trying to run Mocha tests within the Meteor test framework for a certain subset of code in a Meteor project. In particular, this is an internal library that does not actually use any Meteor features, and the test just needs to read in a file, do some computations, and compare results (no server or database or anything). So in theory, this could be its own package with its own testing framework. However, I would still like to use the Meteor test framework if possible just so that I don't need to run two sets of tests. Also, it would be nice to avoid maintaining the dependencies associated with a second test framework. So I have one general and one specific question along these lines:

1. Which testing package (see http://guide.meteor.com/testing.html#mocha or recommend another) is most appropriate for running "plain" Mocha tests, i.e. most similar to just running `mocha` from the command line? It seems to be `dispatch:mocha`, but it "only runs server tests", which doesn't seem ideal. It would help to get some clarification on exactly what "only runs server tests" means and how `dispatch:mocha` differs from plain `mocha`.
2. I was able to get a test sort of working with `dispatch:mocha`, but there were two problems:

   - I had to put the test file in the `server` directory, even though it is shared client and server code.
   - In order to read test data from a file, I had to put the test data in the `private` directory and use `Assets.getText()`. I initially tried (and would prefer) to put the test data in the same directory as my test, but the test gets built in some kind of way that ignores my test data in that case (I can give more details if this is supposed to work).

Is there some way I can avoid the above?